# substring remove just from word with php

Tags: php, string, function

How do I remove parts just from a word in a string and leave intact the rest of it

Having the following situation

```
Notebooks_Lenovo and Tablets
```

I would like to remove the part `_Lenovo` and get back as result

```
Notebooks and Tablets
```

I know as option I have Regex but is there a php function which would do the job

Comment: You could do an simple  str_replace('_Lenovo','','Notebooks_Lenovo and Tablets'); ?

Comment: `str_replace('_Lenovo', '', $string);`

Comment: Give us more details. Do you know what string you have to replace or there is a rule to follow (Like "remove whatever is in a word after a _")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 str_replace("_Lenovo", "", "Notebooks_Lenovo and Tablets");
```

Answer (score 1):

the **str_replace()** function can help you

```
str_replace("_Lenovo", "", "Notebooks_Lenovo and Tablets");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like,

```
str_replace("_Lenovo", "", "Notebooks_Lenovo and Tablets");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = str_replace("_Lenovo ", "", "Notebooks_Lenovo and Tablets");
echo $string;
```